# How can I list which dependencies count against the dex limit for an androidTest apk in AGP 3.0?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

I upgraded to AGP 3.0, but then got a `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException` for the **`androidTest`** apk. I didn't have this issue with gradle `2.3.3`. How can I get a dependency report for exactly which dependencies are being added **only** to an `androidTestApk` (aka dependencies which count against the 65k dex limit)

I tried: `❯ ./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration androidTestApk`

```
androidTestApk - Apk dependencies for 'androidTest' sources (deprecated: use 'androidTestRuntimeOnly' instead). (n)
No dependencies
```

So I tried: `❯ ./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration androidTestRuntimeOnly`

```
androidTestRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for 'androidTest' sources. (n)
No dependencies
```

What should I do?

Note: this issue would be fixed by bumping the minSdk to 21 (but I cannot do that for my main apk)