# How can I set the minSdk just for androidTest?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to increase the `minSdk` to `21` **just for `androidTest`**. Is this possible without introducing a product flavor?

Note: Using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0, and my app's minSdk needs to be `16`.

Comment: hope you tried my solution, did it work? thank you very much if you can/like to come back with some feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can try as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585289/set-different-minsdkversion-for-testandroid-than-for-main-app) suggests creating a new Manifest in the folder where you run your test adding the attribute

> uses-sdk

as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Also is indicated to play in gradle with some if statements in the gradle file, but they are ugly. Anyway you could use it as a plan B solution:

```
if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleDebug")) {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }else{
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the minSdk in either the projects gradle file or manifest. When adding the minSdk it means that you are specifying the minimum sdk level that you have designed and tested your app. You also would want to add the targetSdk. A google support link which may interest you https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

In the manifest it would look like

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    ...
</manifest>`

In your gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.projectName"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

Comment: `minSdk` needs to be `16`. I want to multidex for `androidTest`, so I need to `minSdk = 21` - but for `androidTest only

Comment: You cannot add a minSdk only for testing, you give it for the whole project including tests. On top of that you can multidex prior to 21

Comment: you cannot multidex your test apk. just your app apk

Comment: Your asking the wrong questions and moving in the wrong direction. If you know that you cannot use multidex in test apk why are you trying to add multidex for your tests? I dont really care, either way you cannot have a different minSdk on your tests than your app. It seems like your facing a different problem and your trying to find a solution in the wrong area.

Comment: the methods from your main apk do not count against the methods in your test apk. your main apk can multidex, but not a test apk (`androidTest`).

Comment: What is the problem you are really having cause i dont understand what you are trying to accomplish with having different minSdk versions. And by "test apk" do you mean a debug build?

Comment: I mean the androidTest apk (for espresso tests) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269314/how-can-i-list-which-dependencies-count-against-the-dex-limit-for-an-androidtest

Comment: Ok i think what you need is, @SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18) above the class test?

Comment: no. my build is failing because I need to multidex my test apk.

Comment: are you trying to extend a custom application class? Gradle should also have "testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"" Update the question cause its not a "how to set minSdk for tests" but rather "why are my tests not working"